# Где лежат объекты-прототипы, например, объект HTMLParagraphElement?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

У меня много вопросов по Браузерной Объектной Модели. Непонятного больше, чем понятного. Хочу разобраться в структуре BOM.

**Вопрос 1:** Если взять документ, в элементе `<body></body>`  есть только ОДИН элемент параграф (для простоты) `<p id="1"> </p>` в моем документе с атрибутом id="1", то при анализе браузером моего документа, браузер В ПАМЯТИ строит дерево BOM, куда и DOM входит. Мой элемент становится объектом **p**. Объект **p** занимается КОНКРЕТНОЕ место в BOM - `window.document.lastChild(попал на объект html).lastChile(попал на объект body).firstChild(попал на объект p)`. 
Вопрос: **ГДЕ ЛЕЖАТ ВСЕ ОБЪЕКТЫ ЦЕПИ ПРОТОТИПОВ** параграфа **p** - HTMLParagraphElement, HTMLElement, Element, Node...
Если взять, например, объект-прототип HTMLParagraphElement (`document.getElementById("1").__proto__;`), и спросить "А кто у тебя родитель или сосед?" (`document.getElementById("1").__proto__.parentNode;`), то выдает ошибку **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**.

**Вопрос 2:** Была идея о том, что, может, эти объекты-прототипы лежат в корне объекта window (из тех соображений, что все созданные программистом переменные, объекты, объекты-прототипы, функции ЛЕЖАТ В КОРНЕ объекта window), залез и посмотрел. Наткнулся на какие-то странные функции конструкторы, которые имеют одинаковые с прототипами имена + у них есть свойство `__proto__` и constructor ОДНОВРЕМЕННО. Как у функции-конструктора может быть прототип? Я думал, что прототип только у объекта обычного может быть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос 3:** Оказалось, что у объекта window есть прототип С ТАКИМ ЖЕ ИМЕНЕМ и еще еще дальше прототипы идут. **А они где лежат?**. Я думал, что объект window самый верхний. В общем, путаница какая-то - "что-то в чем-то внутри чего-то".
Помогите, пожалуйста, разгрести эту кашу.

Answer (score 3):

По порядку - кажется вы путаете мягкое с тёплым:

> ГДЕ ЛЕЖАТ ВСЕ ОБЪЕКТЫ ЦЕПИ ПРОТОТИПОВ

Системные конструкторы DOM не обязательно должны где-то лежать. В фаерфоксе видел эти прототипы в исходиках - в виде скрипт-файлов (не JS там был), разве что.

> document.getElementById("1").**proto**;), и спросить "А кто у тебя родитель или сосед?"

У прототипа не может быть родителя в DOM дереве, потому что это прототип: конструктор новых элементов, естественно он к DOM дереву никак не привязан. Может быть "родительский класс" конечно - но это другое.

> Как у функции-конструктора может быть прототип

Легко, читаем https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf .
Функция - это тоже объект, но который может вызываться. Более того с setPrototypeOf очень весёлые приколы можно делать

```js
var mutate = function(mutated, mutateBy) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.appendChain - Not enough arguments');
    }
    if (typeof mutateBy === 'number' || typeof mutateBy === 'boolean') {
        throw new TypeError('second argument to Object.appendChain must be an object or a string');
    }
    var rootProto, oLast;
    var oNewProto = mutateBy,
        result = rootProto = oLast = mutated instanceof Object ? mutated : new mutated.constructor(mutated);

    for (var o1st = Object.getPrototypeOf(rootProto); o1st !== Object.prototype && o1st !== Function.prototype; o1st = Object.getPrototypeOf(rootProto)) {
        rootProto = o1st;
    }

    if (mutateBy.constructor === String) {
        oNewProto = Function.prototype;
        result = Function.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        Object.setPrototypeOf(result, oLast);
    }

    Object.setPrototypeOf(rootProto, oNewProto);
    return result;
};


var list = [8, 3];
list = mutate(list, 'alert("Hello guys!!"+arguments.length+" "); return "ok";');
console.log(list[1]); /*logs 3*/
console.log(list(1, 2, 3)); /*alert, logs 'ok'*/
console.log(typeof list);/*logs 'function'*/
console.log(list instanceof Array);/*logs true*/
```

Поэтому JS самый гибкий язык)

> Я думал, что объект window самый верхний.

Над window есть объект browser - он самый верхний, но он из web-страницы недоступен.

Comment: document.getElementById("1").__proto__; - попадаю на объект HTMLParagraphElement. Это первый из цепочки объектов-прототипов объекта р (который создал браузер, когда проанализировал элемент <p id="1"></p>). Цепь прототипов такая: p --> HTMLParagraphElement --> HTMLElement --> Element --> Node -->... То есть, объекту-прототипу доступны свойства и методы внутри объекта Node. Мало того, что они доступны, так они еще и определены (Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation). Я имел в виду соседей или родителя не по DOM, а в BOM

Comment: раз свойство HTMLParagraphElement.parentNode; определено ВНЕ DOM (оно равно непонятному Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation), то оно, по идее, должно объект-родитель дать в дереве BOM

Comment: То что объекту прототипу доступны свойства родительских прототипов - в этом нет ничего удивительного. А тебе не дают это свойство - потому что просто получение со страницы ограничено. В силу безопасности например такие ограничения часты. Ещё есть такое понятие - как нативные объекты, нативные функции - с ними ничего нельзя сделать, они строго говоря не на JS написаны. Разве что можно расширить протототипы своими свойствами - что я бы делать строго не рекомендовал, вспоминая печальный mootools .

Comment: Хочешь углублённого JS в браузере - попробуй его в плагине фаерфокса. Там меньше ограничений. В плагине JS  бог, он даже может спокойно подключать dll-ки - написанные разумеется совсем не на JS . И юзать оттуда ф-ии, например подключить и юзать WinAPI

Answer (score -2):

1. **parentNode** – это «типа свойство», а не обычное свойство. Для программиста оно кажется обычным свойством, а на самом деле – это пара геттер плюс сеттер, которые являются функциями и имитируют обычное свойство.
   Вызываться «типа свойство» **parentNode** может *только изнутри*, например, объекта-параграфа **p** (`document.getElementById("red"). parentNode;`) и аналогичных – изнутри объектов, которые из элементов документа при анализе получились, так как геттеры и сеттеры у «типа свойств» имеют **this** и эти геттеры и сеттеры запрограммированы только для вызова изнутри параграфа **р** и других объектов, которые из элементов получились.
   То есть, во всей цепи прототипов геттеры и сеттеры стоят в основном, расчет свойств для объектов (для объекта-параграфа **p** (`document.getElementById("red"). parentNode;`) и аналогичных – изнутри объектов, которые из элементов документа при анализе получились) ведется на лету в *динамике*. то есть, они рассчитываются только при обращении к ним, а не постоянно там "сидят", как обычные свойства.
   А когда я писал `document.getElementById("red").__proto__.parentNode;` , то *контекст* был не тот, в котором "типа свойство" **parentNode** запрограммировано работать (там куча **this**). Вот и выдавало фигню **Illegal invocation**.
2. Я хотел узнать, где в дереве BOM лежат следующие объекты: 
   а) Функции-конструкторы для объектов-прототипов function HTMLИмяElement(), function HTMLElement(), function Element(), function HTMLDocument(), function Document(), function CharacterData(), function Text(), function Comment(), function Attr(), function Node()
   +
   б) Одноименные объекты-прототипы HTMLИмяElement, HTMLElement, Element, HTMLDocument, Document, CharacterData, Text, Comment, Attr, Node, которые создаются соответствующими одноименными функциями-конструкорами
   +
   в) функции-конструкторы созданных программистом объектов (Array, Number, Function, Object..., объекты-прототипы созданных программистом объектов (Array.prototype, Number.prototype, Function.prototype, Object.prototype ...

И ошибочно использовал для этого "типа свойства" (а на самом функции геттеры и сеттеры), которые маскируются под обычные свойства (например, name:1) parentNode, firstChild, firstElementChild и другие из объектов-прототипов Node, Element, HTMLElement... Думал, раз свойство определено, то оно должно работать даже в самом объекте-прототипе (в его контексте, то есть изнутри его). Но я тогда не знал про геттеры и сеттеры.

*Куда* конкретно они прикреплены к объекту window – не узнать, так как нет для этого специальных свойств и методов.